# Angular Jest tick not working for debounceTime on RxJS 7

Tags: angular, rxjs, jestjs, angular-jest

I updated my angular application to Angular 13 and everything kept working fine. Then I updated RxJS from 6.6.0 to 7.4.0. After that some unittest failed.

Pseudo test:

```
it('should test some async', fakeAsync(() => {
  component.form.control.get('control').setValue('value')
  expect(component.somevalue).toBeNull();

  tick(999);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.somevalue).toBeNull();

  tick(1);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.somevalue).not.toBeNull();

}));
```

Pseudo code

```
form.control.get('control').valueChange.pipe(debounceTime(1000)).subscribe(x => this.someValue = x);
```

In the test the subscribe never gets a result so it seems `debounceTime` never continues. Any idea how to solve this?

I'm using

```
"@angular-builders/jest": "^13.0.2",
"jest": "27.4.3",
"jest-preset-angular": "^11.0.1",
```

Comment: are you using jasmine marbles (or jest-marbles) somwhere on your tests?

Comment: @SomerandomITboy no, I am not. I am only using the dependencies described above.

Comment: I mentioned because we're using jasmine-marbles (we use jasmine) and turned out that  we had to `npm install jasmine-marbles@latest` in order to get the proper testing version of that due to that the developer had not published the latest version for `jasmine-marbles` due to most people not being in Angular 13 yet. [See this post](https://github.com/CodeSequence/jasmine-marbles/issues/83). Perhaps it's the same forr the underlying dependencies for jest.

Comment: Most likely the problem is that rxjs has changed the way the debounceTime operator works. There is an open issue in angular repo to fix this bug: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/44351

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is an issue. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/44351. Though not ideal, this works for now:

```
it('should test some async', async () => {
    await wait(999);
});

export const wait = (ms: number): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};
```